# Knockout.js: ko.applyBindings(viewModel) -> is there a complete event for applyBinding?

Tags: knockout.js

I have several knockoutjs foreach template bindings which create about 100 `<div class='item' />` in different positions all over my page - all works perfectly except that my subsequent jQuery calls do not work unless I stop in the debugger and wait a second before the jquery bindings are applied:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$(".item").draggable();
```

I was looking for a dataBound event which I could use to apply my bindings AFTER the viewModel has been bound, but I do not find anything.

Comment: Have you considered the `afterRender` binding?

Comment: Sorry, was off for the weekend! Yeah, I take afterRender as this is called for each rendered item. This is where the rendered item is made draggable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Tyrsius mentions you can use the afterRender handler, you can also use the afterAdd handler depending on if you want to add/remove items from your list. These are covered on both the [foreach](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) and [template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) binding docs.

You could also write your own custom binding to do the same, similar to [this example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html). I recommend this as the most maintainable and reusable option but it is sometimes overkill.

That said, if you want to use draggable there is a [great custom binding](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/02/revisiting-dragging-dropping-and.html) already out there which you maybe able to adapt.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks like there is indeed no other other event. As mentioned above I use afterRender for now which seems simple enough for now. But I bookmarked the knockout-sortable Project as I will need it pretty soon :).